# How to add logic to specify posts of particular category_id to display in the loop based upon page_id

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Anyone able to look into the PHP template logic stemming from the **alt_frontpage.php** in the linked folder to determine what changes I should make to which referenced files in order to make this happen?

[Drive link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7yDCnG7HgJ0fkJqTUF1RE1MMG1NQ2pyVHpnZlVGcnlhbXVJRUlQSS1zcEhKdXZ6QUJIbkE&usp=sharing)

In essence, I want each menu option at http://www.geekbardlc.com to link to a specific page.  Each specific page then displays content in the **alt_frontpage.php** template format, but only does so for posts in the matching category.  (e.g. if user selects Storyverse, they see a page with 'storyverse' category posts on the left (featured) and right (sidebar).)

Comment: Have you tried a function? Anyway, please make this question as generic as possible; it helps in making it both clearer and more useful to future visitors. (That means stripping it down to a minimal example of what you have, what you’ve tried, and what you’d like the result to be.)

Comment: Thanks minitech!  It's my first Q here.   The 'suggestions' ask you to be as specific as possible.  I may have overdone it ;)

Comment: Haha, sorry for the conflicting advice! It is great to be specific, but the most important thing to be specific about is what problem you’d like to solve. (More details are good too, of course, but make sure the problem statement is clear – otherwise it’s harder to answer.)